# Powershell - notMatch

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to select from a file all the lines which do not match a specific pattern;
I know I have to use -notMatch option of select-string but I just can't figure it out how.
(I'm looking for something like GREP's -v function)
Any example would be useful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the file pattern you're looking for or avoiding?

Comment: i want to search in a C source file the lines on which a function(defined in that file) is called but to avoid the lines on which it is defined or is commented (has // in front)
`select-string "temp.txt" -notMatch -pattern '(void|double|char|int) $f\('`

Comment: $f is the name of the function

Comment: If `$f` is a variable that holds the function name, you need to place the string in double-quotes. Using single quotes creates a string literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you still want to `match` rather than `notmatch`. To exclude the function return type or comments, you need a 'negative look behind asserion'. Perhaps this will do what you require?

```
$f = 'my_function'
select-string test.txt -Pattern "(?<!(void|double|char|int)\s+|//.*)\b$f\b"
```

The `(?<!...)` part says don't match if '...' is found at this point in the source text.

Answer (score 9):

Can't you use the following

```
-notmatch "(?<!(void|double|char|int)\s+|//.*)\b$f\b"
```